Persistence of the sum of two AR(1) Processes
Consider a time-series, $y_t$, that can be disaggregated as the sum of two component parts:
$$y_t = x_{1,t} + x_{2,t} $$
Suppose that each of the component parts is independent and follows a stationary AR(1) process:
$$\begin{align*} 
x_{1,t} &= \phi_1 x_{1,t-1} + \varepsilon_{1,t} \\
x_{2,t} &= \phi_2 x_{2,t-1} + \varepsilon_{2,t} \\
\end{align*}$$
where:
$$\begin{align*} 
\varepsilon_{1,t} &\sim N \left (0,\sigma_1^2 \right ) \\
\varepsilon_{2,t} &\sim N \left (0,\sigma_2^2 \right ) \\
\end{align*}$$
I use simulation to generate long series of $X_1$, $X_2$, and their sum, $Y$. I then estimate an AR(1) model for $y_t$
$$y_t = \phi_y y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{y,t}$$
In my simulation/estimation, I am finding that the estimate of $\phi_y$ is a weighted average of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, where the weight on each component's $\phi_i$ is determined by its proportion of the unconditional variance. That is, I am finding:
$$
\hat{\phi}_y \approx \left ( \frac{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2}}{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} +\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}} \right ) \phi_1 + \left ( \frac{\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}}{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} +\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}} \right ) \phi_2
$$
I am aware of Lütkepohl (1984) (although I have not yet obtained a copy), which supposedly proves that $y_t$ follows a stationary ARMA process.
Is anyone aware of a proof (or able to derive a proof) of either of the following:

That $y_t$ follows an AR(1) process.
That $\phi_y \equiv \left ( \frac{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2}}{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} +\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}} \right ) \phi_1 + \left ( \frac{\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}}{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} +\frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}} \right ) \phi_2$

Finally, is anyone aware of any related proofs that touch on the more general case, when $\varepsilon_{1,t}$ and $\varepsilon_{2,t}$ are correlated?

I may have a come up with a proof, using the auto-covariance function to show that when $\phi_y$ is defined as above, the ACFs of $y_t=x_{1,t}+x_{2,t}$ and $y_t=\phi_y+\varepsilon_{y,t}$ are identical at all lags. I will type it up later. I am still interested in a citation that shows this result if anyone has one. Thank you.

Hi Adam: Check out Granger and Morris. It's ARMA(2,1) but following the paper is the challenge. http://rainbow.ldeo.columbia.edu/~alexeyk/Papers/GrangerMorris1976.pdf Note that this is not the same result as the paper I was describing in the time scaling question  because that one describes the result for independent blocks of m length sums which is exactly was the OP was doing. Here it's just a plain old sum of two different AR(1) processes.

After reading Granger and Morris (1976) (thanks, @mlofton), it appears that $Y$ does not follow an AR(1) process, but instead follows an ARMA(2,1) process. Further, it takes some algebra, but I can show that setting $\phi_y$ as I suggested above matches the ACF at lag one, but not beyond. We can see this by inspecting the autocovariance.
Suppose that there is a value $\phi_y$ such that the model:
$$\begin{align*} y_t &= \phi_y y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{y,t} \end{align*}$$ is equivalent to the model:
$$\begin{align*} y_t &= x_{1,t} + x_{2,t} \end{align*}$$
First, some variance definitions. From the model $y_t = \phi_y y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{y,t}$, we have:
$$ \begin{align*} \text{Var}(Y) &= \frac{\sigma_y^2}{1-\phi_y^2} \end{align*}$$
From the other model, $y_t = x_{1,t} + x_{2,t}$ and the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, the unconditional variance of $Y$ is given as:
$$ \begin{align*} \text{Var}(Y) &= \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2) \\
\text{Var}(Y) &= \frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2}
\end{align*}$$
So one condition of model equivalence is that:
$$ \frac{\sigma_y^2}{1-\phi_y^2} = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_2^2} $$
Another condition of model equivalence is that all autocovariances between the two models should be identical. That is, it should be the case that $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+k})$ should be the same for both models, for all values of $k$. Let's start with $k=1$. From the AR(1) model $y_t = \phi_y y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{y,t}$, we have:
$$
\begin{align*} 
\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+1}) &= \frac{\sigma_y^2}{1-\phi_y^2} \cdot \phi_y \\
\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+1}) &= \text{Var}(Y) \cdot \phi_y 
\end{align*}
$$
From the other model, we have:
$$\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+1}) = \text{Cov}(x_{1,t}+x_{2,t},x_{1,t+1}+x_{2,t+1}) $$
Given the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, we have:
$$ \begin{align*} \text{Cov}(x_{1,t}+x_{2,t},x_{1,t+1}+x_{2,t+1}) &= \text{Cov}(x_{1,t},x_{1,t+1}) + \text{Cov}(x_{2,t},x_{2,t+1}) \\
\text{Cov}(x_{1,t}+x_{2,t},x_{1,t+1}+x_{2,t+1}) &= \text{Var}(X_1) \cdot \phi_1 + \text{Var}(X_2) \cdot \phi_2
\end{align*} $$
Setting the autocovariances at $k=1$ from each model equal to each other, we have:
$$\begin{align*} \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+1}) &=  \text{Cov}(x_{1,t}+x_{2,t},x_{1,t+1}+x_{2,t+1}) \\ 
\text{Var}(Y) \cdot \phi_y &= \text{Var}(X_1) \cdot \phi_1 + \text{Var}(X_2) \cdot \phi_2 \end{align*}$$
Solving for $\phi_y$ yields the expression for $\phi_y$ from my original question (from here, just plug in for $\text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2)$):
$$\begin{align*} \phi_y &= \frac{\text{Var}(X_1)}{\text{Var}(Y)} \cdot \phi_1 + \frac{\text{Var}(X_2)}{\text{Var}(Y)} \cdot \phi_2
\end{align*}$$
However, setting $\phi_y$ this way means that the autocovarainces at $k=2$ and beyond will no longer match. At $k=2$, from the AR(1) model for $Y$, we have:
$$ \begin{align*} \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+2}) = \text{Var}(Y)\cdot \phi_y^2 \end{align*} $$
From the other model, we have:
$$\text{Cov}(x_{1,t},x_{1,t+2}) + \text{Cov}(x_{2,t},x_{2,t+2}) = \text{Var}(X_1) \cdot \phi_1^2 + \text{Var}(X_2)\cdot \phi_2^2 $$
These two expressions for covariance should be equal if $Y$ can be represented by an AR(1) process. They are not. There are a number of ways to see this. For one, the value for $\phi_y^2$ from solving these equations is different from the value for $\phi_y^2$ by directly squaring the value found from manipulating the first autocovariance. This implies a contradiction.
A final note...generating a long (T=10 million) time-series of $Y = X_1 + X_2$, and estimating an AR(1) model results in a well-identified estimate of $\phi_y$ at the value suggested in my question. On the other hand, estimating an ARMA(2,1) on $Y$ results in parameter estimates with standard errors that three orders of magnitude larger than the standard error from the AR(1) estimate, and worse AIC/BIC statistics. If $Y$ truly follows an ARMA(2,1), this seems strange.
